# Chart.js not rendering chart with data from mySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, chart.js

I am having trouble rendering a chart with data from a mySQL database. My php file seems to be working fine since the JSON array displays correctly when I print it with **print json_encode($var)** I'm not really sure what the issue might be as the canvas remains empty when I open the HTML file.

**chartindex.php**
Retrieves data from the database.

```
   <?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

if(!$conn){
  die("Connection error: " .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$tablequery = sprintf("SELECT ratingid, variety, quality, serving, presentation, value, speed, courtesy, knowledge, location, ambience, cleanliness FROM data ORDER BY ratingid");
$tableresult = mysqli_query($conn, $tablequery);

$data = array();
foreach ($tableresult as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($conn);
print json_encode($data);
}
 ?>
```

**app.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost/mychart9/chartindex.php",
     method: "GET",
     success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var rating = [];
      var variety = [];
      var quality = [];
      var serving = [];
      var presentation = [];
      var value = [];
      var speed = [];
      var courtesy = [];
      var knowledge = [];
      var location = [];
      var ambience = [];
      var cleanliness = [];

      for(var i in data) {
        rating.push(data[i].ratingid);
        variety.push(data[i].variety);
        quality.push(data[i].quality);
        serving.push(data[i].serving);
        presentation.push(data[i].presentation);
        value.push(data[i].value);
        speed.push(data[i].speed);
        courtesy.push(data[i].courtesy);
        knowledge.push(data[i].knowledge);
        location.push(data[i].location);
        ambience.push(data[i].ambience);
        cleanliness.push(data[i].cleanliness);
      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: rating,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Variety',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            //backgroundColor: 'blue',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 128, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: variety
          },
          {
            label: 'Quality',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: quality
          },
          {
            label: 'Serving',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: serving
          },
          {
            label: 'Presentation',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 128, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: presentation
          },
          {
            label: 'Value',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: value
          },
          {
            label: 'Speed',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.9)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: speed
          },
          {
            label: 'Courtesy',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: courtesy
          },
          {
            label: 'Knowledge',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(128, 128, 0, 0.4)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: knowledge
          },
          {
            label: 'Location',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: location
          },
          {
            label: 'Ambience',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.8)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: ambience
          },
          {
            label: 'Cleanliness',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            data: cleanliness
          }
        ]
      };

      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartdata,
        options: {
          barValueSpacing: 20,
          title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'FEEDBACK CHART',
                fontSize: 20
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Rating options'
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Amount'
              },
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

**bargraph.html** - chart canvas

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ChartJS - BarGraph</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #chart-container {
        width: 1000px;
        height: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart-container">
      <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the wrong format, you are pushing it into an array, but it needs to be comma separated values:

```
data: 20, 5, 34, etc ....
```

So in this part of your code:

```
var rating = [];
for(var i in data) {
    rating.push(data[i].ratingid);
    variety.push(data[i].variety);
    ...
  }
```

It should be:

```
var rating; // set to string, not array

rating = rating + data[i].ratingid + ',';
```

Or if it's a string:

```
rating = rating + "'" + data[i].ratingid + "',";
```

Hope that helps.